# How to connect a subdomain on hostinger.com to Laravel?

Tags: laravel, subdomain, hosting

Can you please tell me how to implement a subdomain for example `api.example.com` on hosting hostinger.com?

I created this domain on the hosting and its folder is in `/public_html/api/`, but I don't know how to connect it to Laravel.

The `index.php` file from Laravel is located in the `public_html` folder, and the `public_html` folder is not in the laravel folder because the hosting itself [requires it](https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/6152127-how-to-deploy-laravel-8-at-hostinger).

[image]

Comment: Is example.com redirecting to your laravel application?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi no, this is just an example URL.

Answer (score 1):

While creating a subdomain in the hostinger. It will create a folder inside the `public_html`. So you can find your subdomain in `public_html/api`. You have to add your project inside the `/api` folder.
Make sure to add the `.htaccess` and if needed `server.php` inside the project.
You can get the sample file of these in github. for your reference I am attaching an image. Please check.

[image: Subdomain in public folder]

Comment: I don't want to create a separate project for the subdomain. I want my laravel project to manage both the main domain and the subdomain if possible.

Comment: Just let you clear if you have a HRMS project and you want to run in the main as well as the subdomain. then deploy the code in you public folder it will map to the main domain. and for the subdomain deploy the code inside the folder. so that you can access the project differently in different url.